# No color change for text with Hyperlinks

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have written this style to change color of a div and text on mouseover. The problem occur at the texts with hyperlinks.
Its coming perfect in Firefox and Chrome but its not working in IE. I am using version 10.

Need some help here...

This is the style...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .buttonstyle {
        height:30px;
        width:200px;
        background-color:#FFF;
        font-family:"Arial";
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#767676;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .buttonstyle:hover {
        background-color:#007DBA;
        font-family:"Arial";
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#FFF;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="buttonstyle"><a href="#">Button</a></div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFmgb/)

Comment: I suggest you create a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) to illustrate the problem.

Comment: also post your HTML code.

Comment: This is the full HTML code
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.buttonstyle {
 height:30px;
 width:100px;
 background-color:#CCC;
 font-family:"Arial";
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#000;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.buttonstyle:hover{
        background-color:#007DBA;
        font-family:"Arial";
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#FFF;
 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="buttonstyle"><a href="#">Button</a></div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that only the color and the background of the div get changed on hover. To get the links to change color aswell, you need to say so in CSS.
It might even be better to say that all child-elements of the div need to change color and background on hover. You can do it by using the below style:

```
.buttonstyle
{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
}

.buttonstyle *
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #767676;
}

/*
Or use ".buttonstyle:hover, .buttonstyle:hover a"
if it must only apply to links
*/
.buttonstyle:hover, .buttonstyle:hover * 
{
    background-color: #007DBA;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYxdB/6/)

Edit: I've changed the CSS a bit to make sure the link keeps the same look, even after having clicked on it. Also updated the JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks.But my problem is the text color is not changing in Internet explorer. its working fine in Mozilla and Chrome.

Comment: Which Internet Explorer version are you using? I tested it in IE10 and it worked

Comment: I am also using IE 10 but no result  :(

Comment: Try checking the CSS of the links that aren't changing color. You can check it using the IE Developer Tool (F12). It might be possible another class is overwriting the CSS for links of the .buttonstyle-class.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to see exactly what the issue is without seeing a fiddle or the HTML, but if you're issue is that links inside .buttonstyle aren't changing color, you can specify them like this:

```
.buttonstyle:hover a { color:#FFF; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.buttonstyle {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #767676;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
}
.buttonstyle a {
color: #fff;
}
.buttonstyle a:hover {
color: #fff;
}
.buttonstyle a:active {
color: #fff;
}
.buttonstyle a:visited {
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No color change for text with Hyperlinks,
in the css or style:
color:inherit;